# How can I create custom themes Pluma editor for anyone to use?

Tags: filesystem, mate, colors, installed-programs, theme-development

Ubuntu MATE 20.10 groovy

[image] This "Pluma" code editor comes with Ubuntu mate

> [image] (screenshot from https://mate-desktop.org/)

In `pluma > preferences > fonts & colors > Color scheme` it states:

> You can add a new color scheme by clicking on Add..., and selecting a color scheme file
> You can remove the selected color scheme by clicking on Remove

**Where are these files placed?** and are they CSS files? I would like to create some additional themes for everyone to use.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from the existing ones. For example **Oblivion** color scheme:

> ```
> $ dpkg -S oblivion
> libgtksourceview-3.0-common: /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/oblivion.xml
> ```

The line above says that this file came from `libgtksourceview-3.0-common` package.
It is XML file. Its syntax is covered by [Style Scheme Definition Reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/3.24/style-reference.html).

To start hacking one can create local version of **Oblivion** theme by copying it to the corresponding folder and renaming it to *Oblivion-mod*:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles
cp /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/oblivion.xml ~/.local/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/oblivion-mod.xml

sed -i "s/oblivion/oblivion-mod/g" ~/.local/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/oblivion-mod.xml
sed -i "s/Oblivion/Oblivion-mod/g" ~/.local/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/oblivion-mod.xml
sed -i "s/Dark color/Modified dark color/" ~/.local/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/oblivion-mod.xml
```

and then apply this theme and continously edit the file.

Also note that there are some style collections on the net:

1. https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/cat/279/order/latest/
2. https://github.com/trusktr/gedit-color-schemes